# how to structure rust code to have Vec<Box<dyn FooTrait>> with ability calling BarTrait

Tags: rust

TL;DR;

struc: `TheirPoint`, `TheirLine`
trait: `TheirShadow`, `MySpecialShadow`

```
TheirShadow for TheirPoint
TheirShadow for TheirLine

MySpecialShadow for TheirPoint
MySpecialShadow for TheirLine

let vec_shapes: Vec<Box<dyn TheirShadow>> = vec![Box::new(point), Box::new(line)];
```

**Problem:**

```
for shape in vec_shapes {
  shape.myspecialshadow_function()
//doesnt work - what can be done? Downcast? - but how to handle different types? 
}
```

Long version:
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b573980ca4bac90219914568d8bc662d)

I'm working with a lib <Their*Things*> and use that in <My*Code*>.
Specifically, I use different of their Shapes (`TheirPoint`, `TheirLine`) which have all a common

- output: `TheirOutput` which is an enum
- function: `cast_shadow` provided by Trait `TheirShadow`, which returns `TheirOutput`

I have a `Vec<Box<dyn TheirShadow>>`

```
let vec_shapes: Vec<Box<dyn TheirShadow<Output=TheirOutput>>> = vec![Box::new(p), Box::new(l)];
```

I've created a Trait `MySpecialShadow`, having a function `special_shadow` which I implement individually for `TheirPoint`, `TheirLine`, and I struggle being able to call it during a loop over vec_shapes.

I tried the following without success

```
let vec_shapes: Vec<Box<dyn TheirShadow<Output=TheirOutput, MySpecialShadow>>> = vec![Box::new(p), Box::new(l)];
```

Do you have a recommendation how to structure the code so that a mixed vec based on `dyn Trait` enables call ability to other traits? Downcasting? How would that look like for a mixed vec?

**Thanks for ideas!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the hint @pretzelhammer commented, I've been able to end up with this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2fc3f4589989b70369c2abf71385de04), which works even if not the same struct gets implemented for the different traits, but the struct with trait 1 wrapped in struct with trait 2.

I'm still not sure, if thats the smartest way to go forward, so if there are concepts out there to better achieve such a solution, please share!